# Can a database be made from essays written in college?

Tags: copyright, public-domain, data-ownership, publishing, database

Are graded essays written in college marked for destruction considered published work? What is the legal extent the data from essays can be used?

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/129934/where-do-all-the-essays-go-in-college

Comment: In the US, such essays would be considered educational records and cannot be disclosed to the public without the student's consent.

Comment: @user6726 That is usually not true on the college level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether published or unpublished, they are still protected by copyright. (They are probably unpublished for copyright purposes, but in the US this makes little difference for any recently created work (that is anything  after 2002). For older work see the [Cornell chart](https://copyright.cornell.edu/publicdomain).)

They cannot be copied or distributed without permission, unless an exception to copyright, such as fair use or fair dealing applies. And it is hard to see how either would apply to entire essays simply begin placed in a database. Placing text in a database is probably making a copy, and might be distributing it  or publishing it, depending on how access to the DB is granted.

Now **data** from the essays, as opposed to the texts of the essays themselves, are probably facts. Facts are not protected by copyright in any Berne Convention country, including the US, the UK, and the EU.

Comment: Copyright just because you wrote something is not the same as a legally enforceable filed copyright.

Comment: Actually it is. There is no such thing as a "filed copyright."

Comment: I am not trying to demean your answer, but that isn't true.

Comment: @Putvi To file an infringement suit in US federal court, IF the work was first published in the US, by a US national, the copyright must be **registered**. That can be done as late as the day before suit is filed. Copyright is fully enforcable prior to registration. If the work was registered prior to the infringement, **or** withing 3 months of publication, statutory damages and legal fees may be available, otherwise not. None of the registration requirements apply to non-US works or non-US authors, because of Berne.

Comment: Yeah and if the works are not registered which most college essays would not be, he wouldn't get sued.

Comment: @Putvi  Under 17 USC 408, the holder can register the copyright at any time. If within 5 years of publication the registration is "*prima facie* evidence of the validity of the copyright and of the facts stated in the certificate". Under 17 USC 412 If an unpublished, unregistered  work is infringed, statutory damages or attorney’s fees are not available. But a suit for an injunction, or for the infringer's profits or holder's losses is still perfectly valid. For a published work, registration within 3 months of publication suffices for statutory damages.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that in the future the copyright can be registered and there can be an injunction, but that isn't the case right now.

Comment: @Putvi Once the source is destroyed then the copy is technically the new and only source. The omni reader would find keywords and form a copulation of statistical data. I see how the last paragraph can argue what are facts and the majority of the essay could contribute in some way?

Comment: Yeah, you can use the facts, but until the original writer objects you can use the text.